# IronPython C# linkage

Tags: c#, python

Can anyone tell me, how to use methods from C# in ironpython?

I know some basics but don't understand what to do if I don't want to build my C# project as .dll?

Code for the ConsoleApplication1.exe:

```
 using System;
    using IronPython.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

        namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main()
                {
                    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                    engine.ExecuteFile("C:/Users/Vlad/Desktop/kal.py");
                }

                public int Plus(int a, int b)
                {
                    int z = a + b;
                    Console.WriteLine(z);
                    return z;
                }
            }
    }
```

//kal.py

```
print 'test1'
import clr
clr.LoadAssemblyFromFile("C://Users/Vlad/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication1.exe")
import ConsoleApplication1
arith = ConsoleApplication1.Program.Plus(10,20)
print arith
```

Answer (score 0):

just change type of C# application to Class library and reference it to your 
python app.
from solution explorer right click on C# project note and click `Properties` and change appliction type to class library.
you can reference a library to the project from Project>add reference menu.